# Can image-stacking allow this 0.25 m satellite telescope achieve 0.65m resolution?

Tags: artificial-satellite, imaging, space-telescope, reconnaissance-satellite

The BBC News item [UK satellite to make movies from space](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-42654281) describes this newly deployed satellite:

**caption:** Artwork: Manufacturer SSTL calls it Carbonite-2, but Earth-i refers to the satellite as VividX2

[image]

According to [Gunter's Space Page](http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/cbnt-1.htm) it has a 25 centimeter aperture and at about 500 km altitude should have a ground resolution of about 1.5 meters. However, according to the BBC article:

> "We can collect up to 50 frames per second which is a lot of information," explained Earth-i CEO Richard Blain.
>
> "That allows us to stack the individual images and increase our effective resolution, achieving somewhere around 65cm to 75cm," he told BBC News.

How would a high video frame rate improve ground resolution to 65 centimeters for a ten-inch telescope at 500 km?

I have heard of techniques such as "lucky imaging" (it's a real thing) but this is usually to combat atmospheric seeing effects, not the diffraction limit. Also, this [excellent answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20111/12102) points out that atmospheric effects are much less important looking down at the surface than looking up from the surface for apertures well below 2 meters, confirmed by [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20116/12102) as well.

So here, I don't understand how the high frame rate can have such a profound effect so as to push well beyond the [Airy Disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk) diffraction limit of say $1.22 \lambda / D$ which would be about 2.7E-06 radians, or 1.36 meters at a 505 km closest approach (assuming a 550nm central wavelength).

There are other techniques to push beyond this limit, such as [Aperture Mask Interferometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture_masking_interferometry) as described in [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/24182/7982), but that wouldn't be related to high frame rate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The technique is known as "Super Resolution". Basically this involves a few steps, which the general outline is as follows:

1. Knowing the point source performance to a sub-pixel level of your system. You have to move the test target a fraction of a pixel at a time, and calculate the Point Source Function (PSF) for each point. The smaller you can do, the better.
2. Convert this PSF into a smooth function.
3. Take your source image, and deconvolve it, removing the diffraction errors.
4. Combine these with other photos slightly offset.
5. Solve for a solution such that the root image gives the desired value.

This is somewhat similar to images from the [deblurred Hubble Space Telescope](http://www.stsci.edu/hst/HST_overview/documents/RestorationofHSTImagesandSpectra.pdf). The best image I can find of a deblurred Hubble image is [this one](https://books.google.com/books?id=MFHLut0E2y8C&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=Hubble%20spherical%20aberration%20image%20processing&source=bl&ots=AXHIz12ZI8&sig=T57Qt8dN71UYlx5FxpYsUDrdMoE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilvLbx09LYAhWk5YMKHczyBZs4FBDoAQgxMAE#v=onepage&q=Hubble%20spherical%20aberration%20image%20processing&f=false):

[image]

To give a bit better example of how super resolution is used, take a look at [this site](https://amundtveit.com/2017/06/04/deep-learning-for-image-super-resolution-scale-up/). Image not included because I'm not sure of the copyright, but it shows that you can add multiple images together to get a reasonable image out. You need to have at least the same number of pixels of data to get a reasonable output, so to double the resolution, you would need at least 4-5 images. With 50 images per second, it seems reasonable that they could achieve the indicated resolution, albeit not as good as a single image would be with a larger telescope.

Comment: Excellent! I had a hunch you'd nail the imaging question ;-)