# Biggest periscope camera that could fit inside a Starlink satellite; how thick are they?

Tags: design, photography, starlink, optical

[If all Starlink satellites had phone tier cameras & simple scopes, could images processed by their super-resolution imaging network be competitive?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55255/12102) is a cool question and to integrate a reasonable telescope into a Starlink without adding moving or pop-out parts which would challenge stacking, deployment and operation reliability the only way to put a telescope into one is to use a "periscope camera", really just a flat 45° mirror (or prism) so that the optics can live inside the flat package of a Starlink satellite (or a flat cell phone).

So to understand better what kind of high resolution optics could fit into a Starlink (by pushing something else out or shrinking it) a key ingredient is its thickness.

**Question:** What is the biggest periscope camera that could fit inside a Starlink satellite; how thick are the Starlinks?

---

Images from [What is a periscope lens, and what would it mean for future iPhones?](https://9to5mac.com/2020/07/22/periscope-lens/)

[image: On the left is a conventional zoom lens, which requires all the elements to fit within the depth of the smartphone (plus small bump). On the right, is a periscope lens, which allows the length of the lens to be much longer, as the depth of the phone is no longer an issue.]

> On the left is a conventional zoom lens, which requires all the elements to fit within the depth of the smartphone (plus small bump). On the right, is a periscope lens, which allows the length of the lens to be much longer, **as the depth of the phone is no longer an issue.**

...or at least not as much of one. Presumably the Starlink telescopes  would not be *zoom lenses*, in fact they could be lenses or mirrors or a mix of both. But for the best resolution across a wide-ish field, they would still need to be long and have multiple optical elements.

[image: from "What is a periscope lens, and what would it mean for future iPhones?"]

---

From [What is the largest number of identical satellites launched together?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36087/12102)

> Elon Musk [tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1127388838362378241) about an upcoming launch, that hasn't happened yet at the time this question is posted.
>
> > First 60 @SpaceX Starlink satellites loaded into Falcon fairing. Tight fit.
>
> [image: First 60 @SpaceX Starlink satellites loaded into Falcon fairing. Tight fit.]